# ORACLE SQL - Wildcard on rowname

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables - Table1 and Table2.

`Table1.ROrd = 00123` and `Table2.Ord = 123`.

I need to find all values where `Table2.Ord` contains part of the value in `able1.ROrd`.

Since I was getting **invalid number** error, I tried this. But this is not good enough because the values are not exact match.

```
select * from Table1 where to_char(ROrd) in (select to_char(Ord) from Table2)
```

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "contains part of the value", but if your data holds string representations of numbers you could try using the to_number() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform cross join on those tables and compute some *similarities* or a good, old `instr` function's result, then you get something like this (with my sample data, of course):

```
SQL> with
  2    tab1 (ord) as
  3      (select '00123' from dual union all
  4       select 'ab445' from dual union all
  5       select 'xyz'   from dual
  6      ),
  7    tab2 (ord) as
  8      (select '123'   from dual union all
  9       select 'ab556' from dual union all
 10       select 'zyx'   from dual
 11      )
 12  select a.ord, b.ord,
 13         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.ord, b.ord) jwsim,
 14         utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(a.ord, b.ord) edsim,
 15         --
 16         instr(a.ord, b.ord) ins
 17  from tab1 a cross join tab2 b;

ORD   ORD        JWSIM      EDSIM        INS
----- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
00123 123            0         60          3
00123 ab556          0          0          0
00123 zyx            0          0          0
ab445 123            0          0          0
ab445 ab556         78         40          0
ab445 zyx            0          0          0
xyz   123            0          0          0
xyz   ab556          0          0          0
xyz   zyx           55         34          0

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, decide which option suits you most.

`INSTR` is simple enough:

```
 <snip>
 17  from tab1 a cross join tab2 b
 18  where instr(a.ord, b.ord) > 0;

ORD   ORD        JWSIM      EDSIM        INS
----- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
00123 123            0         60          3

SQL>
```

Choose similarity level by yourself, e.g. `60`, but that's probably not what you want in this case:

```
 <snip>
 17  from tab1 a cross join tab2 b
 18  where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.ord, b.ord) > 60;

ORD   ORD        JWSIM      EDSIM        INS
----- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
ab445 ab556         78         40          0

SQL>
```

I guess `instr` produces better result (according to what you described).

Comment: I think no need to have cross join. You can also use exists clause

Comment: Indeed; I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` and `LIKE` to compare the two tables:

```sql
select *
from   Table1 t1
where  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table2 t2
  WHERE  t1.ROrd LIKE '%' || t2.Ord || '%'
)
```

or, if the values are just zero-padded then:

```sql
select *
from   Table1 t1
where  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table2 t2
  WHERE  t1.ROrd = LPAD( t2.Ord, 5, '0' )
)
```